# How to fix flexbox breaking out of 100% width

Tags: css

I am having issues with my flexbox breaking the page layout.
In the examples the flexbox seems to ignore the parent's rules and expand beyond 100% without the overflow taking over.

```
<entire_holder style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: min-content auto;">
    <sub_holder1 id="menu">I_expand_to_become_larger!</sub_holder1>
    <sub_holder2 id="main_content">
        <div style="background:pink; width:100%; overflow:scroll;">
        <div style="display:flex;">
        <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </sub_holder2>
</entire_holder>
```

This does NOT happen with a normal div that is oversized. Even though the child is oversized the parent's overflow rule works as expected.

```
<entire_holder style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: min-content auto;">
    <sub_holder1 id="menu">I_expand_to_become_larger!</sub_holder1>
    <sub_holder2 id="main_content">
            <div style="background:pink; width:100%; overflow:scroll;">
                <div style="background:green; width:200%;">
                    I work!
                </div>
            </div>
        </sub_holder2>
</entire_holder>
```

Is there a work around I'm missing or is this one of 'those css things'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some CSS to the `#main_content`. Now it overflows and scrolls like your second example.

```html
<entire_holder style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: min-content auto;">
    <sub_holder1 id="menu">I_expand_to_become_larger!</sub_holder1>
    <sub_holder2 id="main_content" style="display: flex; flex: 1; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="background:pink; width:100%; overflow:scroll;">
        <div style="display:flex;">
        <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
            <div style="background:tan; min-width:200px; margin:10px; display:block;">I dont</div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </sub_holder2>
</entire_holder>
```

Comment: It's almost embarrassing how easy the fix was combined with how much time I wasted trying to get figure out a workaround on my own. :P